# Issues with getting strings from the internet

Tags: java, android

So I'm trying to get my app to take text from a string file on the internet and display that.
But it keeps crashing without giving me errors, so I don't know where the problem is occurring.

Here's a copy of my current code (no errors being shown by my ide)

```
package cara.app;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.entity.BufferedHttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {
int itemNumber = 1;
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final Resources res = getResources();
    final Button exit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ExitBtn);

    exit.setText("Close");
    exit.setHeight(100);

    exit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            finish();
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });

    final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.HomeBtn);
    button.setText("" + res.getString(R.string.News) + "\n\n" +     res.getString(R.string.Story_Title_1) + "\n\n" + res.getString(R.string.Story_Title_2) + "\n\n" + res.getString(R.string.Story_Title_3) + "\n\n" + res.getString(R.string.Story_Title_4) + "\n\n" + res.getString(R.string.Story_Title_5));

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

                    try {
                        OpenNews1();
                    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                        OpenNews();
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        OpenNews();
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
            }
        });

                    // Make sure we're running on Honeycomb or higher to use ActionBar APIs
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
                        // Show the Up button in the action bar.
                        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
                    }

}
public void selfDestruct(View view) {
    // Boom 
}


@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

public void OpenNews()
{
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_open_news);

    final Resources res = getResources();
    final Button next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.NextBtn);
    final Button close = (Button) findViewById(R.id.CloseBtn); 
    final Button back = (Button) findViewById(R.id.BackBtn); 

    // Create the text view
    final TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    textView.setTextSize(22);
    textView.setText(res.getString(R.string.Story_Title_1));   

    final TextView textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    textView1.setTextSize(20);
    textView1.setText(res.getString(R.string.Story_1)); 

    next.setText("Next");
    next.setHeight(100);
    next.setWidth(500);

    close.setText("Close");
    close.setHeight(100);
    close.setWidth(1000);

    back.setText("Back");
    back.setHeight(100);
    back.setWidth(500);

    close.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            finish();
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });

    next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if(itemNumber == 1){
            textView.setText(res.getString(R.string.Story_Title_2));
            textView1.setText(res.getString(R.string.Story_2));
            itemNumber = 2;
        }
        else if(itemNumber == 2){
            textView.setText(res.getString(R.string.Story_Title_3));
            textView1.setText(res.getString(R.string.Story_3));
            itemNumber = 3;
        }
        else if(itemNumber == 3){
            textView.setText(res.getString(R.string.Story_Title_4));
            textView1.setText(res.getString(R.string.Story_4));
            itemNumber = 4;
        }
        else if(itemNumber == 4){
            textView.setText(res.getString(R.string.Story_Title_5));
            textView1.setText(res.getString(R.string.Story_5));
            itemNumber = 5;
        }
        else if(itemNumber == 5){
            textView.setText(res.getString(R.string.Story_Title_1));
            textView1.setText(res.getString(R.string.Story_1));
            itemNumber = 1;
        }
    }


});

    back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if(itemNumber == 1){
                textView.setText(res.getString(R.string.Story_Title_5));
                textView1.setText(res.getString(R.string.Story_5));
                itemNumber = 5;
            }
            else if(itemNumber == 2){
                textView.setText(res.getString(R.string.Story_Title_1));
                textView1.setText(res.getString(R.string.Story_1));
                itemNumber = 1;
            }
            else if(itemNumber == 3){
                textView.setText(res.getString(R.string.Story_Title_2));
                textView1.setText(res.getString(R.string.Story_2));
                itemNumber = 2;
            }
            else if(itemNumber == 4){
                textView.setText(res.getString(R.string.Story_Title_3));
                textView1.setText(res.getString(R.string.Story_3));
                itemNumber = 3;
            }
            else if(itemNumber == 5){
                textView.setText(res.getString(R.string.Story_Title_4));
                textView1.setText(res.getString(R.string.Story_4));
                itemNumber = 4;
            }
        }


    });
}



public void OpenNews1() throws ClientProtocolException, IOException
{
setContentView(R.layout.activity_open_news);

final Resources res = getResources();
final Button next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.NextBtn);
final Button close = (Button) findViewById(R.id.CloseBtn); 
final Button back = (Button) findViewById(R.id.BackBtn); 
DefaultHttpClient  httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

// Create the text view
final TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
textView.setTextSize(22);
textView.setText(res.getString(R.string.Story_Title_1));   

final TextView textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
textView1.setTextSize(20);

HttpGet httppost = new HttpGet("http://www.akiorourke.com/cara.nl/text.txt");
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
HttpEntity ht = response.getEntity();

BufferedHttpEntity buf = new BufferedHttpEntity(ht);

InputStream is = buf.getContent();


BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();
String line;
while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
    total.append(line + "\n");
}

textView1.setText(total);


next.setText("Next");
next.setHeight(100);
next.setWidth(500);

close.setText("Close");
close.setHeight(100);
close.setWidth(1000);

back.setText("Back");
back.setHeight(100);
back.setWidth(500);

close.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        finish();
        System.exit(0);
    }
});

next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View v) {

    if(itemNumber == 1){
        textView.setText(res.getString(R.string.Story_Title_2));
        textView1.setText(res.getString(R.string.Story_2));
        itemNumber = 2;
    }
    else if(itemNumber == 2){
        textView.setText(res.getString(R.string.Story_Title_3));
        textView1.setText(res.getString(R.string.Story_3));
        itemNumber = 3;
    }
    else if(itemNumber == 3){
        textView.setText(res.getString(R.string.Story_Title_4));
        textView1.setText(res.getString(R.string.Story_4));
        itemNumber = 4;
    }
    else if(itemNumber == 4){
        textView.setText(res.getString(R.string.Story_Title_5));
        textView1.setText(res.getString(R.string.Story_5));
        itemNumber = 5;
    }
    else if(itemNumber == 5){
        textView.setText(res.getString(R.string.Story_Title_1));
        textView1.setText(res.getString(R.string.Story_1));
        itemNumber = 1;
    }
}


});

back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if(itemNumber == 1){
            textView.setText(res.getString(R.string.Story_Title_5));
            textView1.setText(res.getString(R.string.Story_5));
            itemNumber = 5;
        }
        else if(itemNumber == 2){
            textView.setText(res.getString(R.string.Story_Title_1));
            textView1.setText(res.getString(R.string.Story_1));
            itemNumber = 1;
        }
        else if(itemNumber == 3){
            textView.setText(res.getString(R.string.Story_Title_2));
            textView1.setText(res.getString(R.string.Story_2));
            itemNumber = 2;
        }
        else if(itemNumber == 4){
            textView.setText(res.getString(R.string.Story_Title_3));
            textView1.setText(res.getString(R.string.Story_3));
            itemNumber = 3;
        }
        else if(itemNumber == 5){
            textView.setText(res.getString(R.string.Story_Title_4));
            textView1.setText(res.getString(R.string.Story_4));
            itemNumber = 4;
        }
    }


});}}
```

Comment: If it is crashing, you must have something in your logcat view.

Comment: "But it keeps crashing without giving me errors" not even an Exception?

Answer (score 1):

you must get `NetworkOnMainThreadException` because you have tried connect to internet on UI thread. you can see [This Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception) to solve your problem, you need use AsyncTask or Handler.

you get that error in following code:

```
try {
       OpenNews1();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
       OpenNews();
       e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
       OpenNews();
       e.printStackTrace();
     }
```

in `OpenNews1` you trying connect to internet.